# How to do svn update without password on crontab

Tags: ssh, password, authentication, subversion

I'm new to svn and ssh. I'm trying to do svn update of 5 repositories in my local system every 3 hours on crontab.
So, to achieve this I have setup `ssh passwordless login` using the below steps:

1. `ssh-keygen`
2. `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub test@repo.test.in`
3. I did `ssh test@repo.test.in`

Until here it works fine for me. I'm able to login without password.
But, when I try to do `sudo svn update` on the 5 repositories, it is prompting for password. 
How to make svn update without password. Is there any way that I can do update of the repositories every 3 hours on cron.

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205149/automating-svn-update), but could not get it.
I'm using

```
Ubuntu version : Ubuntu 13.04`         
OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
```

Comment: Why are you using sudo here? Which protocol are you using for svn? Is there a passphrase on the key? You left out about half of the description of your setup, so it's difficult to know what you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

The credentials for `ssh` have nothing to do with `svn`. The subversion server that you're updating against maintains it's own credentials. This is usually kept by the `svn` client itself.

It can depending on the form of authentication to the Subversion server but most of the time they're stored in the user's home directory here:

```
$HOME/.subversion/auth/svn.simple/
```

When you run `svn` update you can instruct `svn` to keep a cached copy of your Subversion credentials in this location. The client will often times do this for you.

#### Example

To do a checkout from this Tigris SVN repository the following file would look like this:

```
$ more ~/.subversion/auth/svn.simple/1b0af524248084a040c5e6aa659031e2
K 8
passtype
V 6
simple
K 8
password
V 0

K 15
svn:realmstring
V 63
<http://svnwcrev.tigris.org:80> CollabNet Subversion Repository
K 8
username
V 5
guest
END
```

So all you should have to do is run the `svn update` command as the user that runs/owns the cronjob, and cache your credentials in this user's account there, similar to how I've explained above.

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
sudo ssh test@repo.test.in
```

you will notice that you have to provide a password. Make sure that works without password first (e.g. by appending your `~/.ssh/id_rsa` private key to `/root/.ssh/id_rsa`)

As you seem to have to run the update using `sudo`. you probably should just make this a cron job for `root`

Comment: ssh works fine without password

Comment: Then svn is not using ssh to connect. Expand your question (not in a comment) with the information how you first checked out the repositories on your local system.

Answer (score -3):

I do it by running "svn update" manually once, it is then prompt you whether to store the password or not.
Once you choose to store it, it will work without password.

Comment: How is this different from the recommendation @slm gave more than half an hour ago?

Comment: 1. for start it is much simpler 2. that is none of your concern